Issue in flutter application while creating user in firebase db
I am facing an issue in flutter application while creating user using firebase db. The user successfully created in authentication in firebase, but not in firestore.
This is the error i am encountered:

W/System  ( 9991): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System  ( 9991): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/tergooglesigni( 9991): Background concurrent copying GC freed 63914(2787KB) AllocSpace objects, 9(308KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3305KB/6611KB, paused 965us total 100.504ms
D/FirebaseAuth( 9991): Notifying id token listeners about user ( WsAb4Bc7dEgbw3FQdmsRQZbWMQZ2 ).
D/FirebaseAuth( 9991): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( WsAb4Bc7dEgbw3FQdmsRQZbWMQZ2 ).
I/flutter ( 9991): Error occurred: Error: type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'PigeonUserDetails?' in type cast
I/flutter ( 9991): <<<-----------------------------------------------: Error: type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'PigeonUserDetails?' in type cast--------------------------------------------->>>
F/crash_dump32(13059): crash_dump.cpp:474] failed to attach to thread 180: Permission denied
I/tergooglesigni( 9991): Thread[6,tid=10003,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x9b400e10,peer=0xa06401e8,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/tergooglesigni( 9991):
I/libc    ( 9991): Requested dump for tid 9991 (tergooglesignin)
I/tergooglesigni( 9991): Wrote stack traces to tombstoned

This is my authentication.dart code :
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthServices {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<String> signupUser({
    required String name,
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    if (name.isEmpty || email.isEmpty || password.isEmpty) {
      return "Error: Invalid input parameters";
    }

    String res = "An error occurred"; // Default error message

    try {
      // Create a new user with email and password
      UserCredential userCredential = await _firebaseAuth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

      if (userCredential.user != null) {
        String uid = userCredential.user!.uid;
        print("User ID: $uid");

        // Add user details to Firestore under 'users' collection
        await _firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).set({
          'name': name,
          'email': email,
          'uid': uid,
        });

        print("Successfully added to Firestore");
        res = "Successfully executed";
      } else {
        res = "User creation failed: user is null";
        print("Error: User creation failed");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Log detailed error message
      res = "Error: ${e.toString()}";
      print("Error occurred: $res");
    }

    print("<<<-----------------------------------------------: $res--------------------------------------------->>>");
    return res;
  }
}


From this it seems that running flutter pub upgrade firebase_auth solved their issues.

I am already done this, but no use.
